# Ionic : The custom hardware button function won't unsubscribe

Tags: ionic-framework

I set custom functions for the back button of the device, but I can't reset the back button to its default purpose : going back. Whenever I set a custom function, I can't unsubscribe it, it keeps the custom function...

Basically I have 2 pages, Home and Quizz, in the quizz page I set a custom function to the back button so it opens a modal used as a confirmation popup

quizz-page.ts

```js
    //import
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-quizz',
      templateUrl: './quizz.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./quizz.page.scss'],
    })
    export class QuizzPage implements OnInit {
    
    private subscriptionBack: Subscription;
    
    async leaveQuizz(){
        console.log("leave quizz request");
        if(await this.statsService.checkSoundState()){
          this.nav_fx_sound.play();
        }
    
        this.subscriptionBack = this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(9999, () => {
          console.log('Setting back button to close confirmation popup!');
          this.modalController.dismiss();
          console.log("SUBSCRIPTION TO CLOSE POPUP WITH BACK : ");
        console.log(this.subscriptionBack);
        });
    
        const modal = await this.modalController.create({
          component: ConfirmationPopupPage,
          cssClass: 'modalCss2'
        });
    
        modal.onDidDismiss().then(value => {
          this.subscriptionBack = this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(9999, () => {
            console.log('Setting back button to leave quizz!');
            this.leaveQuizz();
            console.log("SUBSCRIPTION TO QUIT QUIZZ WITH BACK : ");
          console.log(this.subscriptionBack);
          });
        })
      
        return await modal.present();
      }
    
    ionViewWillEnter(){
        this.ngOnInit();
        this.subscriptionBack = this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(9999, () => {
          console.log('Setting back button to leave quizz!');
          this.leaveQuizz();
          console.log("SUBSCRIPTION TO QUIT QUIZZ WITH BACK : ");
        console.log(this.subscriptionBack);
        });
      }
    
      ionViewWillLeave(){
        this.subscriptionBack.unsubscribe();
        console.log("unsubscribing");
        console.log("UNSUBSCRIPTION TO QUIT QUIZZ WITH BACK : ");
        console.log(this.subscriptionBack);
      }
    
    }
```

But when I go back to home page and click on the physical back button, it either does nothing or it opens the confirmation popup

I can share the logs, this might help :

When I navigate to the Quizz page and click for the first time on the back button (it opens the confirmation popup) :

```
http://localhost/src_app_quizz_quizz_module_ts.js - Line 199 - Msg: Setting back button to leave quizz!
http://localhost/src_app_quizz_quizz_module_ts.js - Line 162 - Msg: leave quizz request
http://localhost/src_app_quizz_quizz_module_ts.js - Line 201 - Msg: SUBSCRIPTION TO QUIT QUIZZ WITH BACK :
```

Then the 2nd time I click (it closes the confirmation popup) :

```
http://localhost/src_app_quizz_quizz_module_ts.js - Line 167 - Msg: Setting back button to close confirmation popup!
http://localhost/src_app_quizz_quizz_module_ts.js - Line 169 - Msg: SUBSCRIPTION TO CLOSE POPUP WITH BACK :
```

Finally I leave the quizz page :

```
http://localhost/src_app_quizz_quizz_module_ts.js - Line 207 - Msg: unsubscribing
http://localhost/src_app_quizz_quizz_module_ts.js - Line 208 - Msg: UNSUBSCRIPTION TO QUIT QUIZZ WITH BACK :
```

But when I click on the back button again in the home page, I get :

```
http://localhost/src_app_quizz_quizz_module_ts.js - Line 167 - Msg: Setting back button to close confirmation popup!
http://localhost/src_app_quizz_quizz_module_ts.js - Line 169 - Msg: SUBSCRIPTION TO CLOSE POPUP WITH BACK : 
http://localhost/vendor.js - Line 46075 - Msg: ERROR
```

So despite the 3rd step saying that it got unsubscribed, the last step shows otherwise...
So I can't go back with the back button after this step
And what is even weird is that if I go back to the quizz page and come back to home page again, then the physical back button opens the confirmation popup (inside the home page) and a 2nd click closes it.
I'm really confused